# Some punctuation is unlegible in keyboard input

Tags: bug, user-interface

I was reading [this tremendously useful Vim answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-yanked-text-into-vim-command-line), and found that the <kbd>"</kbd> symbol (a double quote keyboard input) in the command sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>"</kbd> was very difficult for me to read. It's small and blurry enough that I was unsure whether it was an asterisk, especially since it looks so dramatically different next to the code tags (i.e. `"` vs <kbd>"</kbd>). The asterisk is similarly difficult to read, <kbd>*</kbd>.

Can something be done to make the text in keyboard input tags more legible?